# Extracting two numbers in each loop iteration

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a pythonic way for the following code:

```
    for i in range(len(a)/2):
       print a[2*i], a[2*i+1]
```

In each loop iteration I want to extract the next two numbers.

Btw, I'm using Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grouper` from [`itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

usage:

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
>>> for a, b in grouper(a, 2):
...     print a, b
...
a b
c d
e f
g h
i j
```

Answer (score 2):

You can skip the numbers, with the `range` function itself, like this

```
for i in range(0, len(a), 2):
```

It will start with `0` and iterate till `len(a)`, but it will increment the value of `i` by 2. So your logic can be written simply like this

```
print a[i], a[i+1]
```